# How to remove the background of a noisy image and extract transparent objects?

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation, background-subtraction

I have an image processing problem that I can't solve. I have a set of 375 images like the one below (1). I'm trying to remove the background, so to make "background substraction" (or "foreground extraction") and get only the waste on a plain background (black/white/...).

[(1) Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H86LT.jpg)

I tried many things, including createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2 from OpenCV, or threshold. I also tried to remove the background pixel by pixel by subtracting it from the foreground because I have a set of 237 background images (2) (the carpet without the waste, but which is a little bit offset from the image with the objects). There are also variations in brightness on the background images.

[(2) Example of a background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64h8N.jpg)

Here is a code example that I was able to test and that gives me the results below (3) and (4). I use Python 3.8.3.

```
# Function to remove the sides of the images
def delete_side(img, x_left, x_right):
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            if j<=x_left or j>=x_right:
                img[i,j] = (0,0,0)
    return img

# Intialize the background model
backSub = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history=250, varThreshold=2, detectShadows=True)

# Read the frames and update the background model
for frame in frames:
    if frame.endswith(".png"):
        filepath = FRAMES_FOLDER + '/' + frame
        img = cv2.imread(filepath)
        img_cut = delete_side(img, x_left=190, x_right=1280)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_cut, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        mask = backSub.apply(gray)
        newimage = cv2.bitwise_or(img, img, mask=mask)
        img_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(newimage, (5, 5), 0)
        gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(img_blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        _, binary = cv2.threshold(gray2, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        final = cv2.bitwise_or(img, img, mask=binary)
        newpath = RESULT_FOLDER + '/' + frame
        cv2.imwrite(newpath, final)
```

I was inspired by many other cases found on Stackoverflow or others (example: [removing pixels less than n size(noise) in an image - open CV python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943602/removing-pixels-less-than-n-sizenoise-in-an-image-open-cv-python)).

[(3) The result obtained with the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wakul.jpg)

[(4) Result when increasing the varThreshold argument to 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdSdU.jpg)

Unfortunately, there is still a lot of noise on the resulting pictures.

As a beginner in "background substraction", I don't have all the keys to get an optimal solution. If someone would have an idea to do this task in a more efficient and clean way (Is there a special method to handle the case of transparent objects? Can noise on objects be eliminated more effectively? etc.), I'm interested :)
Thanks

Comment: Is the background fixed in your application? I don't think it will be effortless to segment these objects; however, controlling some factor during the acquisition will make this considerably easier.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes the camera that takes the pictures is fixed, the conveyor at the background is always the same. There may only be variations in brightness.

Comment: @cam1234 I suggest using [GRIP](https://github.com/WPIRoboticsProjects/GRIP/releases/tag/v1.5.2). It is a GUI application where you can drag/drop/connect image processing filters and then export the code to Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. For information, I simply change of methodology and use a segmentation model (U-Net) with 2 labels (foreground, background), to identify the background. It works quite well.