# Reading lower and upper threshold arrays when used with inRange

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I was reading on how to filter colors using OpenCV and came across the following snippet.

```
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_red = np.array([0,160,50])
upper_red = np.array([255,255,180])


mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= mask)
```

What does each value in `lower_red` mean?  Does it denote lower and upper limits of H,S,V sequentially? Should it be read as minimum value of `H` as 0 and maximum value of `H` as 255?

I want to filter red color.

Comment: You are correct. However, in OpenCV, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV has a hue range of 0 to 179.

Comment: @J.D. Which means that the above statement is incorrect? It says minimum value of `H` as 0 and maximum value as `255`. Minmum value of `S` as 160 and Max as `255`

Comment: @J.D. [This link](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/05/08/detect-red-circles-image-using-opencv/) mentions hue range for red as 0-10 and 160-180. How could I represent this with `inRange`?

Comment: The range starts exactly in the middle of the red hue.You can perform the inRange twice, with different ranges and then combine the masks using `final_mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask1,mask2)`

Comment: @J.D. Could not understand. Could you explain with an answer?

Comment: @J.D. I tried `lower_red = np.array([0,0,0]) and upper_red = np.array([179,255,255])` but it gives back the original image.
`

Comment: That is correct, you just selected the full range, that means every color. So it returns the full image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are well on your way. I've added some code that shows a solution to your problem - combining two HSV color ranges in one mask.

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2
# load image
img = cv2.imread("HSV.JPG")
# convert to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Create first mask
lower_red = np.array([0,150,50])
upper_red = np.array([5,255,255])
# Threshold the HSV image to get only green colors
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
# apply mask to original image
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= mask)
#show image
cv2.imshow("Mask1", res)

# Create second mask
lower_red2 = np.array([175,150,50])
upper_red2 = np.array([179,255,255])
# Threshold the HSV image to get only green colors
mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red2, upper_red2)
# apply mask to original image
res2 = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= mask2)
#show image
cv2.imshow("Mask2", res2)

#combine masks
final_mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask, mask2)
# apply mask to original image
result = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= final_mask)
#show image
cv2.imshow("Result", result)
cv2.imshow("Image", img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Note: in the result image I show the results if the separate masks were applied to the original image. Of course you really only need the masks, which are black and white.

Comment: How do we know the HUE range? Like I want to know the range for yellow, what would be the way to go?

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyuw4.png) graph has the hue on the x-axis and the saturation on the y-axis. You can also convert an RGB color to HSV like this:    `red = np.uint8([[[0,0,255 ]]])`    
`redHSV = cv2.cvtColor(red, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)`   
`print(redHSV)`. Result in HSV: `[[[  0 255 255]]]` Select a range around this value.

Comment: The plot is helpful. Is there also a corresponding `value` plot?

Comment: @Sophia you may find a [previous answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45071147/5087436) helpful in this discussion, it gives a little more explanation and also goes to show how you can create your own HSV visualizations.